# Unicode Decode Error while trying to extract data from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I am writing a code to extract specific lines from a text file into an output file, and here is what my code looks like:**

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        with open('testfile.txt') as infile:
            for line in infile.readlines:
                if 'Emotion' in line or 'PANS.RESP' in line:
                    outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write('-----------------------------------------------------')
```

**I keep getting this error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Sam/Desktop/readstuff.py", line 3, in 
>       for line in infile:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py",
>   line 26, in decode
>       return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position
>   154: ordinal not in range(128)

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: shouldnt `infile.readlines` be `infile.readlines()`  - I highly doubt line contains any text .... its a "functionpointer" or smth like it (not a python crack here)

Comment: Simply put, you have to read a text file with the character encoding it was written with. Somehow, you should know which encoding that is before you write your code. Then, you write your code to read with that encoding.